# InvalidCastexception upload multiple images

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi everyone I am creating an application using MVC 5, with a code first database,The code below shows the code I am currently trying to use to upload multiple images but I get an InvalidCastexception when trying to cast 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase'.

Thanks for your time and any help with this issue is greatly appreciated.

Images Controller

```
   // GET: Images/Upload
            [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult Upload()
            {
                return View();
            }

            // POST: Images/Upload
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> uploadFiles)
            {

                    HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;
                    foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
                    {
                        int length = file.ContentLength;
                        string type = file.ContentType;
                        string filename = file.FileName;
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("Upload");

            }
```

upload view

```
@{Layout = null;}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="~/Images/Upload" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @if (ViewData.Model != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in ViewData.Model)
                        {
                            <img src="/Images/@item["Path"]" alt="FileUpload   Image" />
                        }
                    }

                    <input type="file" name="uploadFiles" id="FileUpload" multiple="multiple" />

                   <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Upload" id="btnSubmit" />      
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Exception message also tells you which type you're trying to cast and to which type it can't be casted. It's a gorgeous aid...

Comment: Hi Adriano, it says its because i am trying to cast System.String' to type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase'. , which is the file name and type which is causing the issue should they not be string? any idea of alternative thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that

`foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)`

because the enumerator of `HttpFileCollection` will return names of the files (`string`) but not `HttpPostedFileBase` so you will got `InvalidCastexception`

Use `uploadFiles` in the loop instead of `HttpFileCollectionBase`

```
public ActionResult Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> uploadFiles)
{
        foreach (var file in uploadFiles)
        {
            int length = file.ContentLength;
            string type = file.ContentType;
            string filename = file.FileName;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Upload");
}
```

or use `for` and index:

```
HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;
for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
{
     int length = files[i].ContentLength;
    string type = files[i].ContentType;
    string filename = files[i].FileName;
}
```